# Selecting strings from a list of strings having same value

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings eg -

```
spk_name = ['adrsdt1', 'adrsdt1','adrsdt1','adrsdt10','adrsdt10','adrsdt11','adrsdt11','adrsdt11','adrsdt12','adrsdt12']
```

I want to extract the index as well as elements having the same value. Example-

> 

```
Speaker_1 = ['adrsdt1', 'adrsdt1','adrsdt1']
Speaker_10 = ['adrsdt10','adrsdt10']  etc
```

Is there any workaround using list comprehension or any other technique?

Comment: Where's the use of pandas in this? @Sandeep

Comment: @Vishnudev I thought pandas may have a solution if not list comprehension

Comment: Pandas is a data manipulation and analysis library usually used for larger datasets. If you don't intend to do multiple manipulations and your data isn't large, you shouldn't be using pandas. Just use python's powerful inbuilt functions. @SandeepPandey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group like elements together, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

spk_name = ['adrsdt1', 'adrsdt1','adrsdt1','adrsdt10','adrsdt10','adrsdt11','adrsdt11','adrsdt11','adrsdt12','adrsdt12']

{ key: list(group) for key, group in groupby(spk_name) }
```

This requires more space than you really need: given some key value, your problem statement means you can reconstruct its list simply from the frequency. You can do this simply with `collections.Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(spk_name)

c["adrsdt1"] * ["adrsdt1"]
```

Comment: First snippet should be just `groupby` rather than `itertools.groupby`. Also, key can be `f'Speaker_{re.search(r"[0-9]+", key).group()}'`